# How to build a SelectList using IEnumerable instead of a List type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This piece of code has worked well for me in the past:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
 m => m.Per.TypeID,
 new SelectList(
   listItems,
   "Value",
   "Text",
    Model.Per.TypeID
    )
)
```

But this time around I want to build the **SelectList** with a type **IEnumerable**, so I tried the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
 m => m.Per.TypeID,
 new SelectList(
     Model.ListTypes,
     Model.Per.TypeID
 )
)
```

Problem is, now my output doesn't look right: Every item in the SelectList just reads as "*ListType*"

Instead of **"Value"** and **"Text"** Model.ListTypes contains the properties **TypeID** and **TypeName** but I don't understand how to pass these in as parameters for the SelectList.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what is different here, assuming that `ListTypes` is an `IEnumerable` of a type that has `TypeID` and `TypeName` properties... the constructor overload taking the string names of the properties is still available.

You are using a different constructor to before, so the binding doesn't know where to get the display value from (by default it will `ToString` the bound entity).

Simply use the [other constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
 m => m.Per.TypeID,
 new SelectList(
     Model.ListTypes,
     "TypeID",
     "TypeName",
     Model.Per.TypeID
 )
)
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! I had no idea that I could call the properties like that in an IEnumerable. I thought I would need to call it as something like Model.ListTypes.First().TypeName .. Thanks so much!

Comment: @D1v3 This is what is confusing me because your first code sample calls exactly the same constructor. The fact you happen to be giving it a `List<T>` doesn't matter, as the constructor takes an `IEnumerable<T>`. So really, you answered your own question.